# How to tell if data can be used as a predictor in a classification or clustering model?

Tags: distributions, classification, clustering, descriptive-statistics, histogram

I'm currently studying a data science handbook in preparation for job interviews, and I came across a question that I think should be simple, but honestly has me stumped. Here's a screenshot of the context:

[image: context for questions]

Given the context, there are 2 questions that I'm supposed to answer:

1. Consider the table. What concerns do you have about using the data elements as predictors in a classification or clustering model?
2. Consider the histogram. When analyzing the behavior of library patrons by age, what are the risks of using the midpoint of each range?

For Q1, I really dont know. My hunch is that the age range variable might be problematic, because I dont know how that would coded into the model, but Im really not sure.

For Q2, I suspect that using the midpoint could be an issue if the ages within each range are not symmetrically distributed, and so the midpoint would not act as a good representative sample. Is that the most reasonable answer?

Any insight people can offer would be much appreciated.